# PHP Encoding iso

Tags: php, html, encoding

I am working on a university website where I have the access to the body of any page, I cant change the encoding of pages. The pages use this encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I want to include another file called content.php

```
include('content.php');
```

when I do that this is what happen
[image]

The problem is that I can not find any text editor to convert content.php to 
iso-8859-1 encoding. I tried different types encoding for the content.php like iso-8859-6 but nothing works.

Someone please suggest solution to this encoding problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to look at this [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

wrap your string in this function

Comment: Since ISO-8859-1 is for *Western European Languages*, I doubt it's the correct encoding for you (looks like you're trying to handle Arabic or possibly Hebrew or such).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Notepad ++

[image: Notepad++]

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

To

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```